# Java iText Static Container On Page

Tags: java, itext

I'm generating PDF's with the iText java lib, how can I add a static container to the bottom of my page? I want to use it for a signature, it must be on every page if there are more than one page, always it the bottom left corner?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use [`PdfPageEventHelper.onEndPage()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPageEventHelper.html#onEndPage%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter,%20com.itextpdf.text.Document%29) to add content to every page, as described in [this example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104).